# Bootstrap tooltip not visible in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to implement bootstrap tooltip, but it seems to be hidden behind some other content. When i hover an element with rel="tooltip", the tooltip div is generated to the DOM, but is not visible in the browser. I have Z-index is not causing the problem. Any help appreciated:)

Here is my code:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require modernizr
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-multiselect
//= require bootstrap-scroll-modal
//= require i18n
//= require i18n/translations
//= require flashy
//= require colorfont
//
//= require avatars_for_rails
//
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./social_stream
```

Icon with tooltip:

```
<i class="icon-ok-sign" rel="tooltip" title="Tooltip"></i>
```

tooltip init:

```
jQuery ->
  $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({ delay: { show: 400, hide: 100 }, container: "body", animation: "true"})
```

Result in DOM from console when hovering:

```
<div class="tooltip" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: 495.5px; ">Tooltip</div>
```

As you can see, it only renders the outer div, and the is not removed from the DOM on mouseOut. Also - the classes 'in' and 'fade' are never added to the tooltip, although 'display=' changes between 'block' and 'none' when hovering. So it looks like part of it os working.. very weird:/

Comment: Have you tried pulling down the current twitter-bootstrap-rails gem? gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'  Also this may or may not be it, but I noticed you are missing the ; at the end of your jquery.  I'm not that familiar with coffeescript yet.

Comment: I am building my app on top of the social-stream gem, which loads all the jquery and bootstrap files, but i can see that my current version of bootstrap-tooltip.js is 'v2.3.2'. I dont see any js errors in the console either

Comment: Adding the ";" to the end of the jquery didn't fix it?

Comment: unfortunately not. I also tried changing it to normal js, but no result. Also - the classes 'in' and 'fade' are never added to the tooltip, although 'display=' changes between 'block' and 'none' when hovering. So it looks like part of it os working.. very weird:/

Comment: I don't think your markup is right man, take a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips . I think it should be something like this <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a> . Where rel="" would be data-toggle="tooltip".

Comment: Try to change the z-index, if no console error.. Or may be your tool tip didn't initialize. It has to be either of the two case.